# Select a generic type based on a condition

Tags: swift, generics

I cannot figure out how to select a generic type dynamically based on a given condition. For example:

```
let someCondition: Bool = ...
var model = someCondition ? SomeStruct.self : [SomeOtherStruct].self

doSomething(modelType: model) { result in
    ...
}

func doSomething <T: Codable>(modelType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    ...
}
```

The ternary operation above in line 2 results in the following error: `Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'SomeStruct.Type' and '[SomeOtherStruct].Type'`

Any idea what the solution or workaround would be? Thanks in advance.

[Edit]

To elaborate a little more, the idea is that `doSomething()` performs a request and receives a JSON payload which, depending on the URL, returns a given structure (e.g. `SomeStruct` or `[SomeOtherStruct]`:

`https://sandbox.somecompany.com/foo/chart/1d` returns a payload which can be mapped to `SomeStruct`.

`https://sandbox.somecompany.com/foo/chart/5d` returns a payload which can be mapped to `[SomeOtherStruct]`.

The network request is exactly the same, all that changes is the parameter specified in the URL (i.e. `1d` or `5d`). I could separate this function in two -one for each case-, but I was wondering whether this could be unified in one function using generics.

Comment: The generic type `T` can be both a single object or an array.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make sense. What type is `result`? As written, it could be one of two types, in which case, how can the `...` in the completion handler be written, given that it doesn't know the type of `result`? What code is inside of your completion handler? That will drive the correct way to design this. (Most likely, the completion handler is different in the two cases, in which case you should just use an `if` statement that calls `doSomething` which each of the possible types and the correct completion handler, in which case the problem evaporates.)

Comment: Alternately, you're missing a protocol that you needed, which would unify `SomeStruct` and `[SomeOtherStruct]`. Again, the completion handler code would show you what that protocol needs to look like.

Comment: And you can't have different resulting types when using a ternary operator

Comment: @RobNapier, I just edited the question and elaborated a little more. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @titusmagnus, so you can use your generic `doSomething<T: Codable>(...)` function, but you'd need to give it both the type you want, and the url from which to get it. It should not try to determine it itself

Comment: I agree with New Dev that this is probably structured incorrectly. This is a very well-explored problem. A couple of approaches: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE and https://davedelong.com/blog/2020/06/27/http-in-swift-part-1/

Comment: Thanks everybody for the pointers. Much appreciated.